# I'm having trouble Looping through a folder and writing into another folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

So I have been trying to iterate through a folder containing pictures, convert the pictures to a new format and save the new pictures into a new folder.

```
    import sys
    import os
    from PIL import Image, ImageFilter

    first_folder = sys.argv[1]

    result = sys.argv[2]


    if not os.path.exists(result):
        os.makedirs(result)

    for filename in os.listdir(first_folder):
        img = Image.open(f'{first_folder}{filename}')
        img.filter(ImageFilter.SHARPEN)
        split =os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
        img.save(f'{result}{split}.png', 'png')
        print('Pictures Converted')
    print ('all pictures in png format in the new folder')
```

when I run "python converter.py old_folder new_folder" I get this error message below

```
File "converter.py", line 18, in <module>
    img = Image.open(f'{first_folder} {filename}')
  File "C:\Users\scorpio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2809, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'old_folderpic2.jpg'
```

Comment: add `/` after directory

Answer (score 0):

you're missing folder separator, try this:

```py
import sys
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter

first_folder = sys.argv[1]

result = sys.argv[2]


if not os.path.exists(result):
    os.makedirs(result)

for filename in os.listdir(first_folder):
    img = Image.open(f'{first_folder}\{filename}')
    img.filter(ImageFilter.SHARPEN)
    split =os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
    img.save(f'{result}\{split}.png', 'png')
    print('Pictures Converted')
print ('all pictures in png format in the new folder')
```